# Importing ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin gives ImportError

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, ctypes, python-import

Really stupid question here, sorry - it's my first day in Python.

I want to import the 'IsUserAnAdmin' function like so:

```
from ctypes.windll.shell32 import IsUserAnAdmin
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong because I'm getting:

> ImportError: No module named 'ctypes.windll'

Everything works fine when I import the entirety of 'ctypes', but I don't really want to do that as I'd rather call the function with:

```
IsUserAnAdmin()
```

...than:

```
ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
```

Could someone tell me how I should be importing this function to do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`windll` is a `LibraryLoader` object not a `module`. If you read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ctypes.html), you will notice the import been done as:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> print windll.Shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
0
```

`windll = LibraryLoader(WinDLL)` where `WinDLL` is a class whose doc reads:

> This class represents a dll exporting functions using the
>   Windows stdcall calling convention.

So you can do:

```
>>> IsUserAnAdmin = WinDLL('Shell32').IsUserAnAdmin
>>> IsUserAnAdmin()
0
```